# Returning arrays/dictionary as a property?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that returns a Dictionary with specific keys assigned:

```
Private Function GetScalingAnchorPoints() As Dictionary(Of String, Double)
    Dim x, y, w, h As Double
    Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)

    shape.GetBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, False)

    result.Add("TopAnchorX", y + h)
    result.Add("TopAnchorY", x + (w / 2))

    GetScalingAnchorPoints = result
End Function
```

Then in other method I would get the result of function by using this syntax:

```
Dim ScalingAnchor As Dictionary(Of String, Double)
ScalingAnchor = GetScalingAnchorPoints()
SetSize(ScalingAnchor("TopAnchorX"), ScalingAnchor("TopAnchorY"))
```

I wonder can I return the result as a property instead referring as a key to the Dictionary, so I want to make it like `ScalingAnchor.TopAnchorX`, *without* making another public class to store the property?

Comment: No that's not possible.  You could do something like that with `Option Strict Off` and an `ExpandoObject` but then it's not a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Yea it doesn't have to be a Dictionary. I suppose storing it in a class is a better approach then.

Comment: If you know at design time what the "properties" will be then yes, you should define a type with the appropriate properties.

Comment: Dictionary is a very odd choice, this property should surely return a Point.

Comment: This is not a function but a Sub. where is the `return` statement? How are you able to store `results` inside `GetScalingAnchorPoints`? Is it a global variable?

Comment: @Simo It shows the "old" way of returning a value from a function: *FunctionName = value*. ETA: Documentation: [To return a value using Exit Function or End Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-procedure#to-return-a-value-using-exit-function-or-end-function).

Comment: what a weird way :o

Comment: Glad you pointed that out. Yeah I'm still inheriting my old habit from VB6 and I'm still learning my way on coding. Speaking of which this is a snippet of code from CorelDRAW API so yeah this function returns a Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new class but as you said, you want to avoid this option (but probably is the best one). Otherwise, this might help you:

```
Private Function GetScalingAnchorPoints() As Dictionary(Of String, Double)
Dim x, y, w, h As Double
Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)

shape.GetBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, False)

result.Add("TopAnchorX", y + h)
result.Add("TopAnchorY", x + (w / 2))

return result
```

End Function

First I suggest you to add a `return` statement at the end of your function in order to improve readability of your code.

Now it's time to call it inside your main code:

```
Dim ScalingAnchor As Dictionary(Of String, Double) = GetScalingAnchorPoints()
'Do your stuff here
```

Now you can call your `TopAnchorX` with the following syntax:

```
ScalingAnchor.item("TopAnchorX")
```

This is the most similar way of doing it if you don't want to create a new public class

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using a Class anyway because as you said there's no other way and I liked typing with Intellisense. Your answer might be useful in some cases later.

Comment: Thanks alot @Ran_TH Appreciate it.